# UIScrollview, other controls, not scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have an app which shows two images housed within a UIScrollview.
The scrollview is of size (320, 530), underneath it is an imageview size (320,38), this acts like a dock at the bottom of this screen, ( in fact it has to be there at the bottom of all screens in this app).

As it stand the scrollview works fine and the images switch from one to anothr when the user 
moves the scrollview.

The problem is, I need the scrollview height to go all the way down ( from 530 to 568), and end up behind the dock imageview, when I change its height and the height of images within it, it just stops scrolling.

Is this impossible in scrollviews? does it have to have all of its screen real estate as top view?

Any solutions for this?

Thanks.

Update : 
so I worked on the alpha and the image constraints, and the bottom imnage is located properly,
still the scrolling is not functioning.this is the latest code with changes.

http://ge.tt/4LYJGWl/v/0?c

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible. Add a full height scroll view to the controller's view, then add the small image view to the bottom. In the scene list at the left move that image view up so it's directly underneath the main view, which will make it a subview of that view rather than the scroll view (you'll then need to move the scroll view up above the image view so the image view will appear on top). You'll probably have to change some constraints to pin it to the bottom, and give it an alpha value less than 1 so the scroll view will show through.

[image]

**After Edit**

This is the screen shot of the scene from your updated code:

[image]

You only have one view that's directly under the main view, your scroll view. Compare that to my image.

Comment: I am doing that, but still the behavior is not proper, I created a sample app to show the issue, http://ge.tt/7LgNaVl/v/0?c

Comment: @funkycoldmedia, In the link you provided, you aren't doing what I said in my answer -- that small image view is still a subview of the scroll view not of the main view. You need to move that one up (in the scene list) until it's right under the main view. It should be at the same indentation level when your done as the scroll view

Comment: sorry it was a mistake on my end, I did update the file, still no scroll!!, do I need to implement some delegate method for this?

Comment: @funkycoldmedia, no you don't need any delegate method to do that. The file looks the same to me -- there's still no image view that's not a subview of the scroll view. Look at my edited answer.

Comment: hmm, I downloaded the project and it is not a subview of the scrollview, don;t know if there is a lag or a discrepancy.

Comment: @funkycoldmedia, Ok, I got your new version now. Two things to fix on the little image view. Add a constraint to the bottom of the superview, then delete the one to the top -- this will keep it at the bottom in both iPhone 4 and 5 sizes. Also, as I said in my answer, set the alpha of the image view to something like .5 so the scroll view will show through.

Comment: so I did change the imageview, the scrolling is still not happening.

Comment: are you setting the content size of your scrollview in viewDidLoad? if not, try that.